# EC2 nginx config and SSL for ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to add an AWS ALB for my EC2 instances. I created Application Load Balancer for two EC2 instances as well as ALB with auto-scaling group but none of these works.  The individual EC2 instance is running OK which I tested but the ALB public IP is getting an error page. I wonder if EC2 nginx need to configured differently and whether adding SSL to ALB or to both EC2 instances. I am hosting an react nodejs app on the ECs. Can anyone give me some direction how to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: How did it go. Still unclear about the SSL and ALB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if EC2 nginx need to configured differently and whether adding SSL to ALB or to both EC2 instances

Usually you **add SSL to ALB**. There are only few use-cases where SSL on instances would be needed (e.g. strict regulatory reqquirenemnts for end-to-end encryption). So in general case you would have:

```
Client --- (HTTPS) ---> ALB ---- (HTTP) ---> Instances
```